# How to handle returns correctly in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to do the following:

I had such function:

```
  def terrainFunction(levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos => Boolean = {
    (pos: Pos) => if (levelVector(pos.row)(pos.col) == '-') false else true
  }
```

But I want to catch all the errors in the returned function and return false from it instead of throwing an exception.

So I tried to do this way:

```
  def terrainFunction(levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos => Boolean = {
    val terrFunc = (pos: Pos) => if (levelVector(pos.row)(pos.col) == '-') false else true

    (pos: Pos) =>
      try {
        return terrFunc(pos)
      } catch {
        return false
      }
    
  }
```

The thing is that I get compiler error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Pos => Boolean
Found: Boolean
```

Why does compiler think that I'm returning Boolean, not a whole this function:

```
    (pos: Pos) =>
      try {
        return terrFunc(pos)
      } catch {
        return false
      }
```

And how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `try` nor `return`, rather use proper data types like [`Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html).

```scala
import scala.util.Try

def terrainFunction(levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos => Boolean =
  (pos: Pos) =>
    Try(levelVector(pos.row)(pos.col) != '-').getOrElse(false)
```

Comment: Use `!=`, then no `if`...`else` needed.

Comment: @jwvh right, thanks! I didn't even read the code.